# Count the number of values in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I created a dictionary and want to create a function called `count_type` that will take that dictionary and return another dictionary that is called `count`. This function takes in a `menu` (dictionary) and returns a count (dictionary) that maps each item type to the count of how many items of that type exist in the menu.
 The new dictionary starts looking like:

```py
count = {"Entrees": 0, "Salads": 0, "Sides": 0,
         "Kid's Meals": 0, "Desserts": 0, "Drinks": 0}
```

I want the end result to be the same dictionary but the 0's to be changed to the count of how many times there is a key:value with the value 'Entrees' etc in the original dictionary. an example of what I would like the output to look like:

```
count = {"Entrees": 3, "Salads": 15, "Sides": 3,
         "Kid's Meals": 6, "Desserts": 4, "Drinks": 5}
```

So far I have the code:

```
def count_type(carte):

    count = {"Entrees": 0, "Salads": 0, "Sides": 0,
             "Kid's Meals": 0, "Desserts": 0, "Drinks": 0}
    menu = read_file("menu1.csv")
    ent = 0
    salad = 0
    side = 0
    kid = 0
    dessert = 0
    drink = 0
    for value in menu:
        if value == 'Entrees':
            ent += 1
        elif value =='Salads':
            salad += 1
        elif value =='Sides':
            side +=1
        elif value== "Kid's Meals":
            kid +=1
        elif value =='Desserts':
            dessert +=1
        else:
            drink +=1
```

This loop only gives me a count for `drink` of 46 which is all the values. How do I do this?

The read_file function that I have created already is:

```
def read_file(filename):

    file = open("menu1.csv", "r", encoding='utf-8-sig')
    file.readline()
    menu = {}
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        line = line.split(',')
        item = line[0]
        price = float(line[1])
        cal = int(line[2])
        typ = str(line[3])
        lst= (price, cal, typ)
        tup = tuple(lst)
        menu[item] = tup
    return menu
```

`print(menu)` returns a long dictionary:

```
{'Chic-fil-A Chicken Sandwich': (3.75, 440, 'Entrees'),
 'Chic-fil-A Deluxe Sandwich': (4.45, 500, 'Entrees'),
 'Spicy Chicken Sandwich': (3.99, 460, 'Entrees'),
 'Spicy Deluxe Sandwich': (4.69, 550, 'Entrees'),
 'Grilled Chicken Sandwich': (5.15, 320, 'Entrees'),
 'Grilled Chicken Club': (6.55, 460, 'Entrees')
```

Where some are `'Entrees'`, `'Salads'`, etc.

Comment: Please provide the `read_file` function.

Comment: Can you provide an example as to what your output might be?

Comment: an example of what I would like the output to look like: count = {"Entrees": 3, "Salads": 15, "Sides": 3, "Kid's Meals": 6, "Desserts": 4, "Drinks": 5}

Comment: print the value and type of value and make sure it is what you are checking for in your if statement. Or if you have access to a debugger, put a breakpoint inside the for loop and inspect the value of value, It's probably not what you are checking in the if

Comment: please print `menu` and write it in question

Comment: I may not be understanding the problem correctly, but to increment the dictionary value as you go through the menu, instead of ent += 1, couldn't you do count["Entrees"] += 1. I think we also need to know what the menu variable contains.

Comment: but I suggest you to print `value` in `for value in menu:` and see if your expectation of output is right. you may have wrong values to check.

Comment: the loop keeps counting 46 for drinks and 0 for all the others. which isnt right

Comment: Once you have your issue with the value of value fixed, what you can do is set up the dictionary keys to match what's in value, then rather than a big if statement you can just do count[value] += 1. For an even better solution look at default dict. you can really reduce the code then.

Comment: If you print value using your current code, you will see it referencing 'Chic-fil-a Chicken sandwich', 'Chic-fil-A deluxe sandwich'. Not whether it is an entree or other. You need to go after that specific element

Comment: Value will be a tuple of the three values, so it will never be equal to just the menu item type. You need to get the menu item type from the tuple. try for item, (price, qty, item_type) in menu.items(): and then item_type will be what you want. items() returns the key and the value. The (price, qty, item_type) deconstructs the tuple (unpacks it). If you only ever need the item_type you could just use .values() and unpack the tuple or reference it by index

Comment: the part that says if it is an entree or other is a value to each key. How do I specify that I want it to be counting that value of each key

Answer (score 1):

I recommend  you try: `count[value] += 1` in `for value in menu` loop

Update: you should edit your loop

```
for k,v in menu.items():
    count[v[2]] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you're iterating over the keys of your `menu` dictionary, which is the names of the items (e.g. `'Spicy Chicken Sandwich'`), but you're expecting to have an item type (e.g. `"Entrees"`).

To fix this you need to change your loop. I'd suggest:

```
for _, _, value in menu.values():
    if value == 'Entrees':
        ...
```

I'd note that the name `value` is not very clear what kind of value it is, especially when you're getting a bunch of other data from the dictionary (and throwing them into the `_` variable that will be ignored). Unpacking into more clearly named variables, like `price, cal, typ` again, might make the code clearer.

It might also be a good idea to match `'Drinks'` explicitly, rather than letting any invalid types fall in there. You could have your code raise an exception if it gets an unknown type instead:

```
elif value == 'Drinks':
    drinks += 1
else:
    raise ValueError("Unknown menu item type: {}".format(typ))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop

for value in menu:
instead of checking against value, check against the following

```
for value in menu:
    count[menu[value][2]] += 1
```

and as mentioned above, instead of creating seperate counters for each variables, you can make use of the already created count dictionary by using

```
count["Entrees"] += 1
```

Comment: ohhh okay I see what you are saying! Now how do I count them up and add them to update the count dictionary?

Comment: I updated my answer to answer your question. Instead of creating seperate ent, salad, etc. You can simply do count[menu[value][2]] += 1

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! :)

Comment: Glad to hear :)